# Excel 2016 for Mac - Add row shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm looking for a shortcut to add a row above the current cell in Microsoft Excel 2016. I hate using the mouse.

I saw <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> but it makes the contained text italic.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there are a few possibilities, for example

- hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the row, then <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (Plus Sign) to insert a row above

I don't do Mac, but as far as I know most keyboard shortcuts should work the same if you replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Command</kbd> on a Mac.

Edit: a quick Google search shows the keyboard shortcut you mention in your question, i.e.

Insert a row: Ctrl + spacebar, then Ctrl + i

You need to first select a whole row with Ctrl + space, then, with the row selected hit Ctrl + i.

source: https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/insert-rows

Answer (score 1):

With Excel 2016 on Windows 10, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> (*+ key on the number pad*) and then you are given the option of inserting a cell only and shifting right or down or inserting a row or column.

You can use the underlined letter to specify without having to use the mouse.

Comment: This worked on Office 2016's Excel on my Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for Mac users: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> from the top row of keys seems to work as well (I'm using version Excel for Mac v.15.31). I personally prefer this option as my keyboard requires me to toggle the Numpad on/off using Num Lock.

Comment: Do Macs have “Ctrl” keys?

Comment: Oops, I'm using an external keyboard which labels the `Control` key as `Ctrl`. However yes, Macs do have a `control` key.